# Styling a radio label in an adjacent table cell

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button, css-selectors, label

Ok, I can't effect the HTML being spit out, as it's from a online survey tool. But I can link to my own CSS stylesheet and affect the styling anyway I'd like.

Here is the issue, I have a series of radio buttons with images, and the HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="ChoiceStructure">
  <tr>
    <td class="ControlContainer">
      <input choiceid="1" type="radio" name="QID16" id="QID16-1">
    </td>
    <td class="LabelContainer">
      <span class="LabelWrapper">
        <label for="QID16-1">
          <img src="some/image1.jpg" />
        </label>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="ControlContainer">
      <input choiceid="1" type="radio" name="QID16" id="QID16-2">
    </td>
    <td class="LabelContainer">
      <span class="LabelWrapper">
        <label for="QID16-2">
          <img src="some/image2.jpg" />
        </label>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="ControlContainer">
      <input choiceid="1" type="radio" name="QID16" id="QID16-3">
    </td>
    <td class="LabelContainer">
      <span class="LabelWrapper">
        <label for="QID16-3">
          <img src="some/image3.jpg" />
        </label>
      </span>
    </td>
</table>
```

I'm hiding the actual radio button with this:

```
.ChoiceStructure tr input[type="radio"]{display: none;}
```

What I'd like to happen is have the image or label get a 2px grey border when the item is selected/radio button checked.

I tried this among many other things but can't seem to get it to work.

```
.ChoiceStructure tr input[type="radio"]:checked > td:nth-child(2) span label {
   border:2px solid #4d4d4d;
}
```

I feel like I've tried every solution but the one that works. I appreciate any help that anyone can provide. Thank you.

***EDIT***

I can't do what I'd like with CSS, but was instead directed to look for a Javascript solution. I don't have a way of loading JQuery, or any other frameworks, so I'll need a pure JS solution. I'm not great with JS, I can fiddle with it, but not so good at writing it myself. Any help is appreciated.

***EDIT 2***
I have found a way to load JQuery so that is an option now.

Comment: Do you have anyway of linking to a JavaScript file?

Comment: CSS traverses down only. So unfortunately there is no way to transfer the information that the radio button is checked to the parent and the parent's adjacent elements strictly via CSS.

Comment: The problem is that the CSS selectors can't target an ancestor/parent element, which is what you are trying to do.  If the label and input elements were siblings, then you could do it, but they are each child elements of two separate table-cells.

Comment: I'm looking into whether I can add javascript directly or link to a file.

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes I can add JavaScript. Not a file, but I have a way to input it directly.

Comment: Assuming that you can use `<script>` tags, can you check to see if you can link to the jQuery framework? Thanks! For example: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Let me check better to see if Jquery is possible, I assumed it wasn't, but I'll look better.

Comment: Okay, best thing to do is update your question and tag it with javascript, and make it clear that a JavaScript solution is good for you.  You should get an answer within 90 minutes.

Comment: @MarcAudet Updated and tagged. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution Using jQuery

I build some jQuery actions that will do the trick.

You can refer to the demo code at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/M8zCM/

I am using your HTML snippet and the following CSS:

```
.ChoiceStructure.ex1 .ControlContainer input[type="radio"] {
    display: visible;
}
.ChoiceStructure.ex2 .ControlContainer input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.ChoiceStructure .LabelWrapper img {
    border: 4px solid lightgray;
}
.ChoiceStructure .highlighted .LabelWrapper img {
    border-color: yellow;
}
```

I have two examples (hence the extra class names `.ex1` and `.ex2`).  The first two classes show/hide the radio button and the other two classes add a border around the label image.

The jQuery actions are:

Example 1:

```
$(".ChoiceStructure.ex1 input:radio").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parents(".ChoiceStructure")
        .find(".LabelContainer").removeClass("highlighted");

    $(this).parent(".ControlContainer").next().addClass("highlighted");
});
```

In Example 1, you can click on the radio button and see the image border change color.
Note that you can activate the radio button by clicking on the image that is contained
by the `<label>` tag. Note also that the I first remove the `.highlighted` class from all the
relevant tags first, and then I apply it to the element of interest.

In Example 2, I assumed that the radio button is selected before the page is displayed.
In this case, there is no binding to any mouse event (click).  The jQuery statement
looks for a checked input and then applies the `.highlighted` class to the element.

```
$(".ChoiceStructure input:checked")
    .parent(".ControlContainer").next().addClass("highlighted");
```

As long as you can link to the jQuery framework, you can use this solution.

It would be a lot more work to build this in native JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! I tweaked a little bit, but this got me what I needed. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are very welcome, I had fun working on this problem!  All the best and welcome to SO!